# imported object loses Textures when I change to Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

Well I read the other topics similar to this but would like a fuller explanation on how to fix this problem if there is one. I have figured out how to load static Daz objects into Blender with the texture maps applied. Now that is good news.  But when I change from Blender Render to Cycles some of my excitement is gone as the textures disappear and the object turns white. With the new Blender 7.9 is there an easy way to fix this. I really don't want to unwrap ever model I bring into Blender so I can re-texture it.  How can I keep my materials from the Blender Render to Cycles?

Comment: There is no version 7.9, we are currently at 2.79? You can't just [import models and expect textures to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541#57541), and you certainly can't switch render engines and expect materials to keep working. Remake your materials for the target render engine, no need to unwrap

Comment: Well you are correct on the version that was a goof on my part. I did mean 2.79. How does a person remake the materials for the target render engine? This is the part I am unclear about. I did some checking on the internet and some say  you can fix it in the node editor but don't say how to fix it. The model I have is a low poly man and I tried to put the face texture on his face but it did not go well ha because I was experimenting. So any help would be appreciated.